# Alter table primary key column size to 255

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, composite-primary-key

I have a table with a primary key column size is set to 50. Due to some new requirements, I need to increase the size to 255. After searching online, I understood it is not possible to alter a column if it is a part of a primary key constraint. So, I took the approach of dropping the constraint, altering the column and adding the constraint back.
But, I am still experiencing a small issue, my original column is of type Non Null and has a default value set, but now when i try the following sql, I get an error "Incorrect syntax near DEFAULT"

```
ALTER TABLE [tblLocation] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_tblLocation]

ALTER TABLE [tblLocation] 
ALTER COLUMN Location VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT('New Location') NOT NULL 

ALTER TABLE [tblLocation]
ADD
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblLocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[Location] ASC
)
```

Thanks for any help.
Javid

Comment: You **don't** want to have a `VARCHAR(255)` as your clustering key - trust me !! Read [Kimberly Tripp's blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) on what a good clustering key should be - one point is **narrow** - INT (4 byte) is great, BIGINT (8 byte) is OK, GUID (16 byte) might be tolerable, but anything beyond that - especially a **variable width** column - is insanity.

Comment: Very true, and hopefully he can change it. But how many SO posts have you seen that (perhaps eventually) say "I know the structure sucks, but I can't change it"...?

Comment: @Philip Kelley: too many - but often I wonder if the guy really can't change the structure - or if he's just too lazy to do it..... anyway...

Comment: Why would you bother putting a default constraint on a primary key column? After the first time the default is used, it will always cause a failure. I'd rather get a "can't insert a NULL" error than a "duplicate key violation" error - which won't make sense if I didn't supply a value.

Comment: @marc Unfortunately, its the same reason, too late to change data structure. Its an old table with size 50 being used for years and needs to be increase.
@Aaron I agree, In the original table the column is a composite key and it has a default value. Hence, I wanted to make sure the default value constraint remains.

Comment: @user320587: you could **always** introduce a new `LocationID INT IDENTITY` column, make **that** the clustering key, and avoid any of the problems..... it just takes a little bit of effort ....

Comment: @user320587: seriously - a clustering key on `varchar(250)` is sheer madness - you're just **asking** for trouble down the road..... you should invest the time and [read all of Kimberly Tripp's blog posts](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/Clustering-Key.aspx) on the topic and make use of her insights and follow her advice....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `ALTER TABLE... ALTER COLUMN' to modify both a column *and* a constraint (here, the default) at the same time. You will first need to alter the column, and then alter the default constraint. (You might need to first drop and then recreate the default.)

Comment: Yes, I am using the same approach. I just found that when I alter a column which already has an default constraint, I don't need to re add the default, when the column is altered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the SQL syntax in your second ALTER TABLE statement.

When altering a default value you should specify a constraint name:

```
ALTER TABLE [tblLocation] 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_tblLocation_Location DEFAULT 'New Location' FOR Location
```

(I'm not sure why.  I suppose it's just that the CREATE TABLE syntax alters from the ALTER TABLE syntax.)

However it doesn't make sense to have a default value on a primary key column...